# Adobe Premiere CS6 search slidebar

Tags: video-editor, premiere

CS6 has made it easier for me by making me have to use the keyboard to fast forward without having to hold it, but i preferred the control of being able to use the sort of slidebar.

Does anybody know a way to get this sliding bar speed controller back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This feature was completely removed in CS6](http://blogs.adobe.com/kevinmonahan/2012/07/24/alternatives-to-the-jog-shuttle-controls-in-premiere-pro-cs6/). However, you can now use the keys `J`, `K`, and `L` to scrub the footage.

Comment: Why on earth would they remove this feature. It was fantastic. This combined with no audio on certain files that worked in 5.5 means I'll be sticking with 5.5 sadly. Also, you could use these hot keys in early versions of premier.